# How to get next route after the current route deactivate.?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have some code that uses route 'deactivate' method as follows.

```
 deactivate: function() {
        this._super();
        //some code here

    }
```

Is there a way to identify where is user trying to go(route of URL) after this route deactivates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to use `willTransition` actions method hook for this purpose since that will be called before `deactivate` hook method.

`transition.targetName` will provide the target route.

```
actions: {        
        willTransition(transition) {
            this._super(...arguments);
            console.log('willTransition user ', transition.targetName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is one ugly way to get it from `deactivate` hook but I would not recommend it `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main').router.activeTransition.targetName`