# Single callback in Router, to access previous/current url + Route information?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I've been looking around on Google and Stack Overflow for an answer to this: with Ember-cli 2.10, how can I set up a single callback in the Router, which gives me information about the previous and current URL, as well as the name of the Route about to be called? I'd like to pass all 3 of those to an analytics platform.

Every example I've found has either depended on deprecated Ember features, or just plain hasn't worked as expected. Love to hear an answer on this. Also happy to hear what a better design might be, given the above analytics requirements.

Comment: For previous URL `location.href` and for getting name of the route about to be called can get it from `willTransition` hook `transition` argument using `transition.targetName` refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41543404/5771666). but right now I think we don't have correct exact API for getting the currentURL.

Comment: Hey thanks that's a good start, I took a fresh look and got this far for prior and next URLs:  `const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL,
  didTransitionHook: function() {
    console.log("did transition hook");
    console.log(location.href);
  }.on('didTransition'),
  willTransitionHook: function() {
    console.log("will transition hook");
    console.log(location.href);
  }.on('willTransition')
});`

Comment: ugh: I'm still learning how to show code examples in Stack Overflow!

Comment: `location.href` it's available in anywhere. Why do you need to create observer in Router, there is `willTransition` and `didTransition` hook in available in all the routes and it will bubble from child route to till `application` route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your requirements will be covered in [Public Router Service](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/14805) pull request. It includes properties `currentRouteName`, `currentURL`, `location`, `rootURL` and `transitionTo` method.
It's in canary build, not yet production ready. to play you need to enable this feature `config/environment.js`

```
"FEATURES": {
      "ember-routing-router-service": true
    }
```

You can just inject `router` service anywhere and get the properties.

```
router: Ember.inject.service(),
```

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/862d4acff7bdb79ee318a6c69c07eb2c?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) Copied From  Miguel Camba

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out.